# Show that a function $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is affine

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Fix a point **x** in $\Bbb R^n$. Let **c** be a point in $\Bbb R^n$ and define the function $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ by $$\psi(\mathbf u) = \langle \mathbf c, \mathbf u - \mathbf x \rangle \text{ for } \mathbf u \text{ in } \Bbb R^n.  $$ a. Show that the fuction $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is affine. 
 b. Now show that given any nonconstant affine function $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, it is possible to choose points **x** and **c** in $\Bbb R^n$ so that $\psi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ has the above form.
 Starting with the definition of affine $g(\mathbf u)= f(\mathbf x)  + \langle \nabla f(\mathbf x), \mathbf u - \mathbf x \rangle, f(\mathbf x) = 0 \text { and } \nabla f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf c.  $ I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Affine means that $\psi(\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v) = \lambda \psi(u) + (1-\lambda) \psi(v)$ for all $\lambda$.

In the above case, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi(\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v) &=& \langle c, \lambda u + (1-\lambda) v -x \rangle \\
&=&  \langle c, \lambda (u-x) + (1-\lambda) (v -x) \rangle \\
&=&  \lambda  \langle c, u-x \rangle + (1-\lambda) \lambda  \langle c, v-x \rangle \\
&=& \lambda \psi(u) + (1-\lambda) \psi(v)
\end{eqnarray}

If $\psi$ is affine, note that the function $\lambda(u) = \psi(u)-\psi(0)$ is linear, and any linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written in the form $\lambda(u) = c_1 u_1+\cdots + c_n u_n = \langle c, u \rangle $, for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $\lambda$ is non-constant, we must have $c \neq 0$, hence we can choose $\alpha$ such that $\langle c, \alpha c \rangle = -\psi(0)$, and so we have
$\psi(u) = \langle c, u-x \rangle$, with $x= \alpha c$.